# Android SharedPreferences: How to define keys at runtime?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

The Android documentation describes how to create a "preferences" UI using either a `PreferenceActivity` or a `PreferenceFragment`. The preferences themselves are defined in a XML file (e.g. `preferences.xml`) which contain, among other things, the "key" (`android:key`) to use to store each preference in the app's `SharedPreferences`.

This is good for apps which have a single set of preferences. However let's assume that there is an app that can have multiple "items" (for example: multiple account in a video chat app), and needs to show a preferences screen for each account.

How can this be done? Is it possible to specify the keys at runtime (so that e.g a different prefix can be used for each account)? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Use a different file for each account. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setSharedPreferencesName(java.lang.String)

Comment: Looks like this would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible!
you can assign keys on Runtime like, but as you said in comments that you need to change the Keys of the pre-defined Preferences in Xml rather than creating new Preferences explicitly, here's a method -

```
Preference pref = findPreference("my_pref");
String myPrefix = "prefix_";
pref.setKey(myPrefix + pref.getKey());
```

Comment: How is this done when preferences are not being created explicitly, but instead through `addPreferencesFromResource`? Also, how to do this (add a prefix) for _all_ preferences in the fragment/activity, without having to go through each one?

Comment: @Grodriguez you will have to get each preferences' then add a prefix like - pref.setKey(myPrefix + pref.getKey()); where myPrifix is a String

Comment: "Get each preference", how? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Grodriguez Updated the Answer :)

Comment: Uhm, ok, but there has to be a better way rather than retrieving each preference by name..